# phone number with extensions in android

Tags: android, uri, encode

If a user enters a phone number with an extension I want my android app to be able to call that extension

currently I have a phone number such as

15553244444#6222

I first use

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(TEL + Uri.encode(5553244444 + "#" + 6222)));
```

for some reason the "#" symbol is being shown as "398." after the parse and I am not sure why

my result is

1 555 324 4444 398. 6222

Answer (score 0):

URL encode the number with `URLEncoder`.

`#` has special meaning in URI syntax and needs to be encoded as `%23` to be treated literally as `#`.